# Error:The method is not aplicable for the arguments

Tags: java, sensors

I get the following error

> Error Type:
>   The method extractAccelerometer(BluetoothGattCharacteristic) in the type SensorTagData is not applicable for the arguments (BluetoothGattCharacteristic, TextView)

in the file MainActivity.java

```
  private void updateAccelerometerValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic){

        double accelerometer = SensorTagData.extractAccelerometer(characteristic,mAccelerometer);      //ERROR HERE//
        mAccelerometer.setText(String.format("%.4f", accelerometer));
    }
}
```

and the definition of my class:

```
public class SensorTagData {

    public static double extractHumAmbientTemperature(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {
        int rawT = shortSignedAtOffset(c, 0);

        return -46.85 + 175.72/65536 *(double)rawT;
    }

    public static double extractAccelerometer(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {
        Integer x = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 0);
        Integer y = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 1);
        Integer z = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 2) * -1;

        double scaledX = x / 64.0;
        double scaledY = y / 64.0;
        double scaledZ = z / 64.0;

        return (double) scaledX scaledY scaledZ ;
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Isn't the message clear enough? Mismatch in the number of arguments?

Comment: You are passing the 2 arguments `characteristic` and `mAccelerometer` to a function that only accepts one (probably the first is sufficient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear here :

```
Error Type: The method extractAccelerometer(BluetoothGattCharacteristic) in the 
type SensorTagData is not applicable for the arguments 
(BluetoothGattCharacteristic, TextView)
```

The method signature for `extractAccelerometer` specifies that the method takes only one parameter.

```
extractHumAmbientTemperature(BluetoothGattCharacteristic)
```

However, while making the call to this method, you are passing two arguments. Clearly, there is a mismatch in the number of arguments as is clear from the error message. Any reasonably good IDE should be able to point this out to you.

```
extractAccelerometer(characteristic,mAccelerometer);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    extra argument
```

If your method declaration is correct or the way you wish to define it to be, then the simple way to fix this would be to remoe this extra parameter, and call the function like this :

`extractAccelerometer(characteristic)`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in an extra parameter, `mAccelerometer`. Remove that.

```
double accelerometer = SensorTagData.extractAccelerometer(characteristic); // <-- the extra parameter has been removed
```